# Retrofit arraylist response.body() error inside background runnable thread

Tags: java, android, mvvm, retrofit2

I orginally had retrofit set up in an activity with all the calls being done on the main thread. I'm trying to switch over to a MVVM architecture by having a View model, and a respository. I'm also trying to run the retrofit calls a background thread. However when I try to add the response.body() into a List inside the Runnable method I get an error from the ArrayList stating "cannot infer arguments, unable to resolve constructor".

Code sample below:

API Class:

```
  @GET("readMoodLineGraphToday.php")
Call <List<MoodLogLineGraphTestResponse>> getMoodLogsLineGraphToday(@Query("userId") int userId);
```

Model Class:

```
@SerializedName("moodBefore")
@Expose
private float moodBefore;

@SerializedName("posted")
@Expose
private String posted;

@SerializedName("day")
@Expose
private float day;

@SerializedName("cbtId")
@Expose
private int cbtID;


public MoodLogModel() {
}

public MoodLogModel(float moodBefore, String posted, float day, int cbtID) {
    this.moodBefore = moodBefore;
    this.posted = posted;
    this.day = day;
    this.cbtID = cbtID;
}

public float getMoodBefore() {
    return moodBefore;
}

public String getPosted() {
    return posted;
}

public float getDay() {
    return day;
}

public int getCbtID() {
    return cbtID;
}
```

Response Class :

```
@SerializedName("")
@Expose
private MoodLogModel data;

public MoodLogLineGraphTestResponse() {
}


public MoodLogLineGraphTestResponse(MoodLogModel data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public MoodLogModel getData() {
    return data;
}
```

ApiClient Class :

```
 @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            Response response = getMoodLogsLineGraphToday(userId).execute();
            if(cancelRequest){
                return;
            }
            if(response.code() == 200){
                ArrayList<MoodLogLineGraphTestResponse> list = new ArrayList<>((((MoodLogLineGraphTestResponse)response.body()).getData()));
                //mMoodLogs.postValue(list);
            }else{

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This line : ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>((((MoodLogLineGraphTestResponse)response.body()).getData()));

Throws the error inside the <> after the = new ArrayList

"cannot infer arguments, unable to resolve constructor"

Comment: please log you're data in `response.body()).getData()` and post

Comment: I can't, the app wont compile due to the error stated in the question. The data is an array of JSON strings obtained from an external MYSQL server